# how to change user (www-data) to root

Tags: command-line, permissions, command, file-permissions, chmod

I do not know what happens...but in my laptop, all folders and files have user www-data instead of root.

in directory /desktop /music ....alll directories ..

how can I change user root?

I use command

```
chown -R www-data:root /
chown -R root:www-data /
```

any ideas??
I tried a lot but I am not able to change the user for files and directories.

even I tried lots of commands but I do not know how can I change user as root

Answer (score 5, accepted):

write in command prompt :

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/envvars
```

change :

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

to :

```
#export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_USER=root
#export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=root
```

hope so it will work for you